# React & reducers : can I call the reducer from within itself?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, reducers

small question :

Can I call a reducer from within itself ?
Let's say I would like to call ACTION_1 from ACTION_2, is this possible ?

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ACTION_1':
      return {
        ...state,
        //......
      }
    break;

    case 'ACTION_2':
      var newState = {
        ...state,
        //.......
      }

      //I would like to call ACTION_1 here, and pass newState to it. Is it possible ?
      
 
    break;
  
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }

};
```

Comment: What do you mean by “call”? You can run the same *code*, in various ways.

Comment: The idea is not to have the same code twice. I would like to call another action from the reducer.. Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: `return reducer(newState, { type: 'ACTION_1' })`? Also, you don't need `break` after `return`.

Comment: Has this other action actually happend in your app at that point? If no, you shouldn't *fake* that. Extract the common code and call it in the reducer instead of *re-calling* the reducer.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of approaches

1. Dispatch a new action

```
case 'ACTION_2':
    // do something
    dispatch({ type: 'ACTION_1', payload })
```

2. Extract `ACTION_1`'s body to a separate function, then use it on both

```
case 'ACTION_1':
   return reduceACTION_1(...)
case 'ACTION_2':
   return reduceACTION_1(...)
```

3. Change `switch` statements into an if

```
if (action.type === 'ACTION_1' || action.type === 'ACTION_2') {
   // do something
}
```

---

You have a bit of an odd use-case, though. It's possible you're misunderstanding how to use the APIs to achieve what you want.

Comment: 1. - dispatch a new action does not work; it says `'dispatch' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest calling `some Action` after you have called the `first Action` a side-effect operation

so you can be explicit that when I get `Action2` I need to fire `Action1` as a side effect of that Action.

Helpful side effect library for redux and for the purpose of listening to all action coming in and take only `Action2` so you do the `side effect` you like is `redux-saga` library.

You need to learn a little bit about generators and how the library works but it's very great to achieve what you want.